# open layer: display a label from properties in geojson file

Tags: openlayers

I am new to open layer map. I am trying to display a label on a marker by reading the label from a geojson file.

Here is the format of my geojson file:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type":"Feature","properties":{"label":"1"}, "geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[-81, 42]}},
    ]
}
```

I tried to use attribute replacement to display the label. Here is the code:

```
var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
        'fillColor': '#669933',
        'fillOpacity': .8,
        'strokeColor': '#aaee77',
        'strokeWidth': 3,
        'pointRadius': 8,
        'label': '${label}'
    });
```

However, all the other properties are shown except the label. Could you please tell me how I can display the label from the geojson file?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

```
var vector_template = {
        fillColor: '#669933',
        fillOpacity: .8,
        strokeColor: '#aaee77',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        pointRadius: 8,
        label: '${label}'
    }

var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style(vector_template);
```

It works for me. Otherwise try changing *label* to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try:

```
'label': '${label}'
```

Comment: 'label' might be a kind of key word... try to change it on something like 'displayLabel'...

Comment: It is still not working. Not matter what key words I used in the properties section, the label just did not show up on the map.